# How Can I convert Long to String in Freemarker?

Tags: java, freemarker

I have model

```
class someDto{
private Long id;
private String hz;
}
```

And in page I need show

```
<td><p id="${someDto.id}"></p></p></td>
```

And I see `12 333`
But I need `12333`

How Can I convert `Long` to `String` in Freemarker?

Comment: You *are* converting a long to a string, apparently, but you have a default formatter set.

Answer (score 6):

Use `?c`, which formats for computers as opposed to humans:

```
 ${someDto.id?c}
```

See: http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_number.html#ref_builtin_c